# issue about UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c

I have a table view, and its first row has different style from the rest. After I scrolled the table once, some other rows' style also become that of the first row. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that your tableview cells are *being reused*. So a cell that has been configured for row 0 is then popping back up further down, with its configuration intact. So you've got two options here:

- Completely reset the state of your cells when they're being reused
- Return a cell with one reuse identifier for row 0 and another cell with a different reuse identifier for everything else

When this was mentioned at WWDC it seemed that the second option is preferable, I suspect because it means less messaging of label objects and the like as the table scrolls.

Comment: I would go for the second option otherwise cell identifiers are useless and it also leads to better performance.

Comment: That would seem to be Apple's guidance as well, although with only one cell being the special kind, it's probably going to be a wash in this case. Especially since with #1, you don't end up with an unused cell instance consuming some smidge of memory.

Comment: Perfect – have fun. UITableView is a gnarly little beast but very helpful once you've mastered it.